# "External pointers not valid" when using xml2 in R-package

Tags: r, pointers, shiny, xml2

I'm building a Shiny app as an R-package with `golem`. The idea is to help scientists convert their heterogeneous field data into a common XML format to improve data standardization and interoperability.

The basic architecture is that I define an empty target XML document in `global.R` outside the Shiny server and access it from various modules and utility functions within the app to add nodes and content using the `xml2` package as a backend.

When testing locally with `golem::run_dev()` (which is a wrapper for `shiny::shinyApp`), the app runs smoothly and I can create, edit and export the XML target document. However, when I try launch the app from the built package, I get the following error:

```
Error in write_xml.xml_document(xml_document, tmp, options = "format") : 
  external pointer is not valid
```

Here is a [small example package](https://file.io/UZCnUUo5qAk6) that reproduces the error.

I'm aware that external pointers are only valid within the same R session but I don't know how that relates to my problem. It seems like `global.R` and the app are running in different sessions when launched from the package but not when launched locally?

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar problem: A package which imports an XML file using `read_xml()` yields error messages reading "external pointer is not valid". A possible workaround in my case would be to clone the source package and then run all files in `pkgname/R` in the local session. This is not how a package is supposed to operate, but as long as there is no workaround more elegant, I would recommend this approach.